# gnuplot unable to output image

Tags: shell, gnuplot

I am trying to plot two column data. using first column as label of x axis (configuration) and and the seconds column as the value for the y axis(average_ mpki).

This is how my data looks like:

```
#assoc_valr     blk_sz, cache_sz, rep_pol, avg_icache_mpki
4a128b32c1r     0.000682
4a128b32c2r     3.030329
4a128b16c1r     0.0333616
4a128b16c2r     0.0307207
4a64b32c1r      0.0125913
```

This is my ploting script:

```
# Gnuplot script file for plotting data in file "confs.out"
# This file is called   confs.p

set style data histogram
set style fill solid border -1

filename="confs.out"
set boxwidth 0.15

set xlabel "Configurations"
set ylabel "Average MPKI"
set xtic rotate by -45 scale 0
set output  "confs.png" 
set terminal png size 1200,1200 


plot  "<(sed -n 'confs.out')" using  2:xtic(1)   with histogram
```

I try plotting but it doesn't work, It doesn't throw any warning or error message but still it doesn't generate the output file for me. I can't see output when I try ploting without using the script also. I tried to gather windows to see if it is hidden under my terminal but it is not.

I also tried replacing the space separator with the tab in the data. Still not working.

```
gnuplot> load 'confs.p'
^C
gnuplot> plot 'confs.out' using 2:xtic(1) with hist
gnuplot> exit
```

Comment: Why do you use process substitution (`<()`) in the first place? I'm not sure if gnuplot even understands that. And secondly, what's the goal of `sed -n 'confs.out'`? `-n` suppresses output, and there doesn't seem to be any sed command...?

Comment: @Benjamin `<` can be used in gnuplot to redirect from a command but as you rightly point out, the `sed` command makes no sense at all.

Comment: True. The problem solved once I removed the `<()`. Thanks.